# Is a verb omitted in the second independent clause?

Tags: grammaticality, legalese, ambiguity, gapping

> The basic task of the court is to ascertain and give effect to the true meaning
>   of what Parliament has said in the enactment to be construed. But that is not
>   to say that attention **should be** confined and a literal interpretation ♦ given to
>   the particular provisions which give rise to difficulty. Such an approach not only encourages immense prolixity in drafting, since the draftsman will feel
>   obliged to provide expressly for every contingency which may possibly arise.

Source: p 95, *The English Legal System 2012-2013*, Gary Slapper

Is a verb omitted at ♦? Why or why not? I tried
https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/10165/8712 but am dubious. What's this issue called?

Answer (score 4):

Your crux exhibits a type of ellipsis called [gapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)#Gapping), in which a repeated element common to two coordinated constructions is omitted at its second occurrence.

> that attention            should be confined
>     and                 to the particular provisions, &c
>     a literal interpretation <s>should be</s> given

Here two other examples from the linked article:

> John can play the guitar, and Mary <s>can play</s> the violin.
>
> Fred took a picture of you, and Susan <s>took a picture</s> of me *OR*
> Fred took a picture of you, and Susan <s>took</s> a picture of me

Your example also exhibits Right Node Raising [RNR], in which matter following  coordinated or parallel elements—in this case, the preposition phrase *to the particular provisions which give rise to difficulty*—is 'shared' by them: both *confined* and *given* take that PP as an object/complement.